# how to call beforeDelete event when deleting many side element in a one-to-many association?

Tags: grails

I have a one to many association here both domain classes

**PurchaseOrder**

```
class PurchaseOrder {
  BigDecimal balance

  static constraints = {
    balance nullbale:false
  }

  List items
  static hasMany = [items:Item]
```

}

**Item**

```
class Item {
  String product
  Integer quantity
  BigDecimal price

  def beforeInsert() {
    def balance = purchaseOrder.balance ?: 0

    total = price * quantity
    purchaseOrder.balance = balance + total
  }

  def beforeDelete() {
    purchaseOrder.balance -= total
  }

  static belongsTo = [purchaseOrder:PurchaseOrder]
}
```

In PurchaseOrder class is the field balance, this field(balance) needs to be calculated when an Item object is created or when is updated or deleted.

beforeInsert event in Item class is called and update balance but is not the case when when i try to delete an Item beforeDelete its not called

I am trying to delete item this way

```
purchaseOrderInstance.removeFromItems itemInstance
```

This way no error message and balance property is not calculated

If I try

```
itemInstance.delete(flush:true)
```

I get this error message

```
Error initializing the application: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [ni.sb.Item#2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [ni.sb.Item#2]
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like this. To `delete()` an item from the purchase you must do

```
purchase.removeFromItems (item)
item.delete ()
```

Problem is that `removeFromItems()` would clear the `belongsTo` back reference and your `deleteBefore()` event would fail.

Another problem with this approach is, that as long as the purchase is not saved and your doing something with `balance`, the `balance` would be wrong.

The easiest way to make this work is to recalculate the balance on each access:

```
class Purchase {
    BigDecimal balance

    BigDecimal getBalance () {
        BigDecimal total = 0
        items.each { Item item ->
            total += item.total ()
        }
        total
    }

    List items
    static hasMany = [items:Item]
}


class Item {
    String product
    Integer quantity
    BigDecimal price

    BigDecimal total () {
        price * quantity
    }

    // rest of code ...
}
```

I also recommend to read [gorm gotchas](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/).